Mounting a 2 gang wall plate on Siding
I have a covered  patio and its walls have a cement fiber siding. I want to install a 2 gang wall plate on it.  I was thinking of installing a recessed wall mount like this, and fixing the wall plate on to that. But it is very difficult to find a recessed mount that is big enough to fit a 2 gang wall plate and matches the siding's color (would have thought this as a standard use case). Am I missing something? Is there an alternative way to install the wall plate (I would prefer for the wall plate to be a little recessed)?

Matching the color: Paint.

I mean, you've already got white wall boxes for the existing outlet and the lamp...
